# How can I convert a specific column of datetime into date only?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get the specific column called `date_period` but only the date? I want to convert it not to add another column in the result

I tried this:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)
```

But this will just return another column with the convert of `datetime`. I have many `datetime` columns and I just want the `date_period` to be convert and so I can compare it to another `datetime` that only has a date and 00:00 time.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

And by the way the result I get from what I tried is the date today. Like I said I have many `datetime` columns in one table I just want to convert a single column.

Comment: Remove the original column and use the expression to define a new column.

Comment: `select convert(date,date_period) as date_period`

Comment: @GordonLinoff how can that happen ? How can I target only one in my column. I have many datetime in my table like 3 datetime

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach

```
   cast(columnname as date)
```

Comment: Why tho? Enlighten me please. Thanks.

Comment: Why?  Because its the easiest, cleanest way to convert a datetime to a date.

Comment: Its seems that is for 2012 and above as explained in other answer?

Comment: It is at the very least available on 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like I solved it.

The answer that I found is this

```
REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT (varchar, columnname, 101),10)
```

Thanks for all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, Use the column that is needed for you either expected_date or expected_datetime like below-

```
if object_id('tempdb..#test') is not null
    drop table #test;

create table #test(ts datetime)

insert into #test values (getdate())

select ts as actual_datetime,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),23) as expected_date,
cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),23)as datetime) as expected_datetime
from #test
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you already solved it in your own way but still I would like to add some points for others

You want to extract only `date` part from the `datetime` column, there are some formats available for getting only date part from the `datetime` column. 
Please find the list from the given link to get the date formats.[LINK](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx)

```
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 103)    --- DD/MM/YYYY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 102)    --- YYYY.MM.DD
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 101)    --- MM/DD/YYYY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 104)    --- DD.MM.YYYY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 106)    --- DD MMM YYYY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 107)    --- MMM DD, YYYY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 110)    --- DD-MM-YYYY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 111)    --- YYYY/MM/DD
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 1)    --- MM/DD/YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 2)    --- YY.MM.DD
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 3)    --- DD/MM/YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 4)    --- DD.MM.YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 5)    --- DD-MM-YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 6)    --- DD MMM YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 7)    --- MMM DD, YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 10)    --- MM-DD-YY
select convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 11)    --- YY/MM/DD
```

**NOTE**: This is for older sql version like mentioned `sql server 2008`

For recent sql version 2012 and above

You can directly use `cast` with `date` type data-type.

```
  select cast(getdate() as date)
```